# Lock gem dependency versions for different rubies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

Rubygems doesn't provide a proper way to specify different dependencies for different ruby versions. If we put a conditional in the gemspec, it can switch what gets installed:

```
if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
  # ruby 1.8 only supports nokogiri < 1.6
  s.runtime_dependency "nokogiri", ">= 1.4.0", "< 1.6"
else
  s.runtime_dependency "nokogiri", ">= 1.4.0"
end
```

But, this doesn't control what gets *loaded*. If there's a newer version in the load path, that would get loaded even if it's incompatible with ruby 1.8.

I'm not sure if this is actually a problem: If you're using rbenv/rvm etc. then you have different gem paths for each ruby, so hopefully you'd never have both installed in the same place. I think even the standard gem paths are divided by compatibility versions (1.8 / 1.9.1). Is that intended to take care of this, or could you ever get into a situation where both versions are installed together?

The other approach would be to leave the gemspec open-ended (without the conditional), and warn users to set the correct version constraint in their Gemfile if they need it.

Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just the nature of how bundler and requiring gems works. It's one of the great benefits to tools such as rvm.